# R shiny problem: virtualselectinput covering reactable

Tags: css, r, shiny

The problem, as the following picture is shown, is that the options of virtualselectinput is being covered by the reactable below. I want the virtualselectinput and its options be always on the top of the reactable below. Great appreciation for someone who knows how to style the CSS and solve the problem.

[virtualselectinput covering reactable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neE8G.png)

#reproduce the problem that virtualselectinput covering reactable

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(


        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

        navbarPage(title = "Example", id = "NavBarPage", collapsible = TRUE,

            tabPanel("tabPanel 1", value = "tabPanel_1",

                # uiOutput("ui_for_tabpanel_1"),
                
                fluidPage(

                    fluidRow(

                        column(2,

                           virtualSelectInput(
                               inputId = "selection_A",
                               label = "Select A: ",
                               choices = rownames(mtcars),
                               search = TRUE,
                               multiple = TRUE,
                               showSelectedOptionsFirst = TRUE,
                               maxValues = 1000 
                           ),

                              ),

                        column(2,

                           selectInput(inputId = "watchlists", "Select B: ", 
                                       choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))

                              ),

                        column(2,

                            virtualSelectInput(
                                inputId = "symbols_selected_watchlist",
                                label = "Select C: ",
                                choices = rownames(mtcars),
                                search = TRUE,
                                multiple = TRUE,
                                showSelectedOptionsFirst = TRUE,
                                maxValues = 1000
                            ),

                            ),

                    ),

                    tags$br(), tags$br(), tags$br(), tags$br(),

                    reactableOutput("table_A"),

                    )

            ),

            )

    ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
      output$table_A <- renderReactable({

          reactable(mtcars,
                    fullWidth = TRUE, compact = TRUE, highlight = TRUE,
                    striped = TRUE, filterable = TRUE,
                    pagination = TRUE, showPageSizeOptions = TRUE, defaultPageSize = 100,
                    height = 800,
                    selection = "single", onClick = "select",
                    theme = reactableTheme(

                        rowSelectedStyle = list(backgroundColor = "#808080", boxShadow = "inset 2px 0 0 0 #ffa62d")

                    )
          )

      })

    }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need to adjust the `z-index` of the dropdown menu. We are going to put this number high.

> The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) cover those with a smaller one.

`tags$style(HTML(".vscomp-dropbox-container  {z-index:99999 !important;}"))`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(reactable)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    navbarPage(title = "Example", id = "NavBarPage", collapsible = TRUE,
               tabPanel("tabPanel 1", value = "tabPanel_1",
                        tags$style(HTML(".vscomp-dropbox-container  {z-index:99999 !important;}")),
                        fluidPage(
                          fluidRow(
                            column(2,
                                   virtualSelectInput(
                                     inputId = "selection_A",
                                     label = "Select A: ",
                                     choices = rownames(mtcars),
                                     search = TRUE,
                                     multiple = TRUE,
                                     showSelectedOptionsFirst = TRUE,
                                     maxValues = 1000 
                                   )
                            ),
                            column(2,
                                   selectInput(inputId = "watchlists", "Select B: ", 
                                               choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))),
                            column(2,
                                   virtualSelectInput(
                                     inputId = "symbols_selected_watchlist",
                                     label = "Select C: ",
                                     choices = rownames(mtcars),
                                     search = TRUE,
                                     multiple = TRUE,
                                     showSelectedOptionsFirst = TRUE,
                                     maxValues = 1000))
                            ),
                          tags$br(), tags$br(), tags$br(), tags$br(),
                          reactableOutput("table_A"),
                        )
               )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$table_A <- renderReactable({
      
      reactable(mtcars,
                fullWidth = TRUE, compact = TRUE, highlight = TRUE,
                striped = TRUE, filterable = TRUE,
                pagination = TRUE, showPageSizeOptions = TRUE, defaultPageSize = 100,
                height = 800,
                selection = "single", onClick = "select",
                theme = reactableTheme(
                  rowSelectedStyle = list(backgroundColor = "#808080", boxShadow = "inset 2px 0 0 0 #ffa62d")
                  
                )
      )
      
    })
  }
)
```

[image]